# Angular2 Observable Filter

Tags: filter, angular, observable, rxjs5

I'd like to filter an observable, but am getting unexpected results.

I am using the following import statements:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

This example returns nothing:

```
Observable.of([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
.filter((x: any) => x % 2 === 0)
.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

This example returns the entire result set [0,1,2,3,4,5]:

```
Observable.of([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
.filter((x: number[], idx) => x[idx] % 2 === 0)
.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Does anyone see syntax errors and/or something I am missing?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `from` if you want to pass values as iterable (array in current case)

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';

Observable.from([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
.filter((x: any) => x % 2 === 0)
.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Or if you want stick with `of` pass values as arguments

```
Observable.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
.filter((x: any) => x % 2 === 0)
.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```